# Add texture to .dae 3d model

Tags: 3d, textures, alice

I am trying to download a free model, but when i tried to import it in Alice 3, it said no texture coordinate found. I opened clara.io to see what happens when i import it, and it worked just fine. I loaded all the animations and textures. I exported everything to a new .dea, and it said check if there are any nested animations, so i deleted all the animations, because i dont really need them. Then i tried again, but the txture coordinate error came up, and I was unable to import it.

I dont have any separate texture files.

Answer (score 0):

Does the tool you used for export also allow you to apply a texture? That might be enough to allow import.

More broadly, since the planned use of the imported model is strictly inside the 3D world of Alice and its limited model manipulations there is an expectation that the model will be visually complete. But even with that logic, model import remains overly particular about the imported data details.

Import is still in beta and we are trying to improve it. Can you provide (or point to) the source model?

Comment: http://artist-3d.com/free_3d_models/dnm/model_disp.php?uid=264&count=count , but i have also tried with other models and it still didn't work. And also I had to convert the .3ds to .dae and I used https://products.aspose.app/3d/conversion/3ds-to-dae and some other online converters.